# indefinite integrals equal imply integrands equal?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

if there is an indefinite integral equality
does it mean that there is an integrand equality?
$$\int f(x)\,dx = \int h(x)\,dx \quad \overset{?}{\Longrightarrow} \quad f(x) = h(x)$$

I know that
$$\int f(x)\,dx = \int h(x)\,dx \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \int_A f(x)\,dx = \int_A h(x)\,dx \quad $$
for any arbitrary $A$ and if $f(x),h(x)$ are continuous, then  $f(x) = h(x)$, but how about more general function, discontinuous function?

Comment: I would interpret $\int f(x)\,dx = \int h(x)\,dx$ as there exists a function $F$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ and $F'(x)=h(x)$. In this case, $f(x)=F'(x)=h(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, write the indefinite integral equality as
$$\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)=\color{blue}{\int_a^x f(t)\,dt=\int_b^x h(t)\,dt}=H(x)=\int h(x)\,dx.$$
Then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
{d\over dx}\int_a^x f(t)\,dt=f(x)={d\over dx}\int_b^x h(t)\,dt=h(t).
$$